# 504 gateway timeout for any requests to Nginx with lot of free resources

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, timeout, gunicorn

We have been maintaining a project internally which has both web and mobile application platform. The backend of the project is developed in Django 1.9 (Python 3.4) and deployed in AWS.

The server stack consists of Nginx, Gunicorn, Django and PostgreSQL. We use Redis based cache server to serve resource intensive heavy queries. Our AWS resources include:

1. t1.medium EC2 (2 core, 4 GB RAM)
2. PostgreSQL RDS with one additional read-replica.

Right now Gunicorn is set to create 5 workers (by following the 2*n+1 rule). Load wise, there are like 20-30 mobile users making requests in every minute and there are 5-10 users checking the web panel every hour. So I would say, not very much load.

Now this setup works alright for 80% days. But when something goes wrong (for example, we detect a bug in the live system and we had to switch off the server for maintenance for few hours. In the mean time, the mobile apps have a queue of requests ready in their app. So when we make the backend live, a lot of users hit the system at the same time.), the server stops behaving normally and started responding with 504 gateway timeout error.

Surprisingly every time this happened, we found the server resources (CPU, Memory) to be free by 70-80% and the connection pool in the databases are mostly free.

Any idea where the problem is? How to debug? If you have already faced a similar issue, please share the fix.

Thank you,